# Accidentally changed permissions in root folder

Tags: linux

I believe the permissions in my root folder have been accidentally changed to 666. This of course has had knock on effects for `/bin/`, which means I'm struggling to see how to fix it.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: You need to access the file system from outside. Easiest is to use some rescue system, maybe on CD or USB stick. It allows to run a system from another source and then mount the partition you want to manipulate. Most distributions offer such thing, there are also some specialized distributions for that out there.

Comment: Is there any easy way to restore default/correct permissions on everything?

Comment: Not that I am aware of.

Comment: Okay, thanks. It's a cluster, sadly, so access to the machine is difficult. May just be easier in this case to build from scratch rather than try to save.

Comment: Well, easiest probably is to roll back to the latest backup you took. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In grub selection screen (if this doesn't show up hold shift at boot) select recovery mode and press enter, then select root terminal (or something similar it may be called root shell) from the list of options. Then type mount -o rw,remount / to gain read/write access to the filesystem. Then type adduser username sudo to give the admin user that you changed to standard sudo (root) privileges.